# Unable to serve my application with "ng serve" after upgrading angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I had an Angular 2 application working perfectly, but after upgrading angular cli, I am unable to serve my application with `ng serve`.

I have the following error:

```
ng serve                                  
Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "undefined".
Error: Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "undefined".
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/luisjose/Documentos/TusDividendos/web/tus-dividendos2/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:27:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/luisjose/Documentos/TusDividendos/web/tus-dividendos2/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/eject.js:10:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I followed all the steps as indicated in [Angular CLI migration guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update), this is:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
rm -rf node_modules dist
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

But, as I said, I can't serve my application with `ng serve`.

(Edited)

I didn't know I can run `ng serve` inside a project with `./node_modules/.bin/ng serve`. Thank you Yakov. Anyway I uninstalled angular cli globally to avoid conflicts.

I still can't serve my project but I feel I am near the solution ;-)

The error I get is the same as I posted at the begining:

```
./node_modules/.bin/ng serve       
Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "undefined".
Error: Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "undefined".
    at Object.<anonymous>
...
```

And my package.json is this:

```
{
  "name": "tusdividendos",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "angular2-materialize": "^6.3.0",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.6.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "materialize-css": "^0.97.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "^1.7.0",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

¿Any clue?

Comment: What is the content of your package.json? Have you updated it?

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that "Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater." It seems that the versions of dependencies in your package.json are old. 
Generate a new project and take a look at the dependencies in package.json and update yours as needed. For example, this is what I have in a newly generated project:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
```

Comment: Yakov, thanks for our answer but I have no problems servings new Angular 4 projects. I have the problem with a big Angular 2 project. I have to do minor changes in it and don't want to migrate it to Angular 4.

Comment: You can't use the latest Angular CLI with Angular 2 projects. The last version of Angular CLI that supported Angular 2 was 1.0.0-beta.30, I believe.

Comment: That means that I can't have Angular 2 projects and Angular 4 projects in the same machine?

Comment: You can. Since you have a local version of Angular CLI installed in your project, you can always run it like this: node_modules/.bin/ng serve. 
The other way to do this would be to create an npm script command in your package.json, e.g. "serve": "ng serve". Then run it using npm run serve. This would run the local version of the CLI.